# How to convert SQL code to Entity Framework to fill data to datatable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some SQL code that fills data into a datatable but now I want to use it with Entity Framework. So can you help me to convert this code?

```
public static string UserName
{
    get
    {
        return _UserName;
    }
    set
    {
        _UserName = value;
        _GroupName = Database.GetLoookup("UserName", value, "GroupName", "_Users", true);
        DTPer = Database.GetDataTable(("Select * from _GroupPermissions Where GroupName = \'"+ (GroupName + "\'")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an Entity model?

Comment: Yes I have an Entity model.

Comment: You're showing `Database.GetLoookup()` and `Database.GetDataTable()` -- what class is that?  People will need to see source for these methods to be able to help you.

Comment: This is the link to see my class file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6z6XFNapsDgd2otRktYX011MkU